# Função PL/PGSQL Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, funções

Tenho a seguinte função :

```
create function sppreenchecombomunicipio(p_uf text) returns TABLE(MUNICIPIO 
text, COD_MUNICIPIO int) 
AS $$
begin 
return query select tb_municipio.municipio, tb_municipio.cod_municipio  from tb_municipio  where    UF = p_UF; end; 
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Ela esta funcionando, porem tenho lido na documentação oficial do postgresql que exitem outras formas de fazer esta funcção.

Qual seria a forma "correta" , ou esta forma que postei é a "correta"?

Exemplo da documentação que eu poderia adaptar para meu caso:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo() RETURNS SETOF foo 
AS $BODY$ 
DECLARE 
r foo%rowtype;
BEGIN 
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid > 0 LOOP
    -- can do some processing here
    RETURN NEXT r; -- return current row of SELECT
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Eu faço do mesmo jeito que você usa e funciona para mim. Eu uso para buscar os produtos, tenho uma tabela filha dos preços e organizo por índice.

Answer (score 0):

A única observação é que não é necessário plpgsql, basta sql:

```
create function sppreenchecombomunicipio (p_uf text)
returns table (
    municipio text,
    cod_municipio int
) as $$
    select tb_municipio.municipio, tb_municipio.cod_municipio
    from tb_municipio
    where uf = p_uf;
$$ language sql;
```